# Problem with Array in struct in Julia language

Tags: julia

I've a problem with the following struct:

```
struct OdeSol{typ, rng, n}
    t::rng
    x::Array{typ}
    v::Array{typ}
end

OdeSol(typ, rng, n) = OdeSol(rng, Array{typ}(undef, n, length(rng)), Array{typ}(undef, n, length(rng)))
```

where `t_range=tlim[1]:Δt:tlim[2]`, `typeof(x0[1])` is `Float64` and `size(x0)[1]` is an integer (`size(x0)[1]`=`2`).

When I launch `sol = OdeSol(typeof(x0[1]), t_range, size(x0)[1])` I got the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching Array{0.0:0.01:10.0,N} where N(::UndefInitializer, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Array{0.0:0.01:10.0,N} where N(::UndefInitializer, !Matched::Int64, ::Int64) where T at boot.jl:421
  Array{0.0:0.01:10.0,N} where N(::UndefInitializer, !Matched::Int64, ::Int64, !Matched::Int64) where T at boot.jl:422
  Array{0.0:0.01:10.0,N} where N(::UndefInitializer, !Matched::Integer, ::Integer) where T at baseext.jl:17
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] OdeSol(::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2}) at ./In[10]:8 (repeats 2 times)
 [2] top-level scope at In[11]:1
 [3] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1091
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your error does not match what you claim to have run.  You're passing in a range as the `top`, a matrix as the `rng`, and a matrix as your `n`.  None of those types match what you claim to be calling it with.  This has nothing to do with the `struct` definition at all; take a step back and make sure you know what each argument is.

Comment: You also really want those Array type annotations to be Vector, otherwise the field type is abstract since the number of dimensions isn’t specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing the parametric types with the field values within the `struct`.
On top of that it is worth to use capital letters for type names.
Looking at the parameters it also seems that you are looking for matrices (that is 2-dimensional arrays)/

Perhaps you mean the following thing:

```
struct OdeSol{T, R}
    t::R
    x::Matrix{T}
    v::Matrix{T}
end

OdeSol{T,R}(rng::R, n) where {T,R} = OdeSol{T,R}(rng, Matrix{T}(undef, n, length(rng)), Matrix{T}(undef, n, length(rng)))
```

And now sample usage:

```
julia> OdeSol{Int, Vector{Int}}([1,2,3],4)
OdeSol{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}([1, 2, 3], [0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0], [0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0])
```